# Problem building a hamcrest map matcher in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mockito, hamcrest

I'm working on a simple mock that returns a value when a function in called with a collection that has a given entry.

BUT when I build the matcher

```
import org.mockito.hamcrest.MockitoHamcrest.argThat
import org.hamcrest.collection.IsMapContaining.hasEntry

val matcher : Matcher<Map<String, String>> = hasEntry("key", "value")  as Matcher<Map<String, String>>
val args : Map<String, String> = argThat(matcher)
```

it ends up being null due to generics not being inferred correctly as far as I can see and blows at runtime with

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: argThat(matcher) must not be null
```

Eventually I just want to set up the mock like below:

```
doReturn(returnValue).`when`(referenceObj).functionName(args)
```

My dependencies include:

- mockito-core 2.16.0
- hamcrest-all 1.3
- kotlin-reflect 1.2.30
- kotlin-stdlib 1.2.30
- kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 1.2.30
- kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 1.2.30

**Am I doing something wrong? Can you suggest a workaround?**

Comment: In the end I've just used verbatim arg matcher which works reasonably well for very small maps: 
`doReturn(returnValue).`when`(referenceObj).apply(mapOf(...))`

Answer (score 0):

If you use ham**k**rest https://github.com/npryce/hamkrest for Kotlin instead of hamcrest, you can try to create:

```
fun <K, V> hasEntry(key: K, value: V): Matcher<Map<K, V>> {
    return has("entry $key -> $value", { it[key] }, equalTo(value))
}
```

and then in your test:

```
val map = mapOf("some-key" to "some-value")

assertThat(map, hasEntry("some-key", "some-value"))
```

I found a solution here https://github.com/araqnid/app-status/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/org/araqnid/appstatus/Matchers.kt